# QScroller::grabGesture(ui->scrollArea , QScroller::LeftMouseButtonGesture) in multiple scrollareas in Raspberrypi qt c++

Tags: qt, qscrollarea

**How to use QScroller::grabGesture(ui->scrollArea , QScroller::LeftMouseButtonGesture) in multiple scrollareas in Raspberrypi qt c++**.

```
    #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include "ui_mainwindow.h"

    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(0);

    QScroller::grabGesture(ui->scrollArea_5, QScroller::LeftMouseButtonGesture);
    QScroller::grabGesture(ui->scrollArea_6, QScroller::LeftMouseButtonGesture);
    QScroller::grabGesture(ui->scrollArea_7, QScroller::LeftMouseButtonGesture);

    }

    MainWindow::~MainWindow()
    {
      delete ui;
    }
```

this is my code.
I want to scroll multiple scrollArea . in Raspberrypi qt c++.
there are 3 buttons in total and each scrollArea should scroll if each button is clicked.

I used same code in Window application it works properly but doesn't work in Raspberrypi.

Thank you.